# Project Reactor Documentation

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

Where would one find the documentation for Reactor Core (not an API javadoc), something similar to [Reactor Kafka Docs](https://repo.spring.io/milestone/io/projectreactor/kafka/reactor-kafka-docs/1.0.0.M1/reactor-kafka-docs-1.0.0.M1.zip!/docs/index.html), which one could read.  Does it exist?
How is Reactor's documentation structured, its [dedicated page](https://projectreactor.io/docs) doesn't seem to contain reference docs for all the modules except Reactor Kafka, only APIs.  Is that by design?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your linked documentation page **does** contain reference docs (for Reactor Kafka). That's what is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not by design *per se*, but the reference guides don't exist for Reactor 3 core **yet**, it is our next focus. Reactor-Kafka development better handled this and produced documentation immediately, but it is very focused on the Kafka use-case.

Comment: randomly coming back to this question. the reference guide has since then been released for reactor-core at projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/docs/index.html

Answer (score 4):

While and until there's no official documentation on Reactor 3 core yet, as per @Simon Baslé's answer, I found the following resources to be of great help in learning Project Reactor:

- [Reactors PR announcement](https://spring.io/blog/2016/09/27/ready-your-java-8-reactive-apps-now-reactor-3-0-ga-is-out)
- [Dave Syer](https://spring.io/team/dsyer)'s reactive series [part I](https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/07/notes-on-reactive-programming-part-i-the-reactive-landscape), [part II](https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/13/notes-on-reactive-programming-part-ii-writing-some-code) & [part III](https://spring.io/blog/2016/07/20/notes-on-reactive-programming-part-iii-a-simple-http-server-application) with [code](https://github.com/dsyer/reactive-notes)
- [Reactive Stream](http://www.reactive-streams.org/)'s official page with its [API](http://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-1.0.0-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/package-summary.html) description and explanation of [goal](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-io/issues/1), [design](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm) and scope, as well as the Project Reactor's own [javadoc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/) with its excellent visual diagrams
- **Developing Reactive applications with Reactive Streams and Java 8** presentation at Devoxx by [Brian Clozel](https://github.com/bclozel), [Sébastien Deleuze](https://github.com/sdeleuze) with its [speakerdeck](https://speakerdeck.com/sdeleuze/developing-reactive-applications-with-reactive-streams-and-java-8), [video](https://youtu.be/Cj4foJzPF80), [1st](https://github.com/reactor/lite-rx-api-hands-on/) and [2nd](https://github.com/bclozel/spring-reactive-university) parts of live coding
- Spring 5 documentation has some good resources on [Reactive Web Applications](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M4/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html)
- Reactor's [Gitter](http://gitter.im/reactor/reactor), where one can ask questions

Perhaps they'll be useful for someone else getting to know Reactive Project as well.